# While Loop stops before condition

Tags: c, while-loop

I have a problem with my code. I want to load a dictionary which works fine with a small one. But when i try to load the larger version, my while loop stops at the 701th word which is " acclimatization" and then the programs continues. I searched a lot on forums and tried a lot of things, but i just can't find the reason this is caused. Does anyone have an idea of how this occurs?

Dictionary.c

```
bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
// reserve space for word
char* word = malloc(sizeof(char*));

// open file
FILE* dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");

if (dict == NULL)
{
    fclose(dict);
    fprintf(dict, "Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
    return 1;
}

root = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
root->is_word = false;

//Loops over word aslong the EOF is not reached
while (fgets(word,LENGTH,dict) != NULL)
{
        printf("word = %s\n", word);
        int word_length = strlen(word) -1;
        node* current = root;
        word_count++;
        //Loops over letters
        for (int i = 0; i < word_length; i++)
        {
            int index;
            node *next_node;
            // checks if letter isnt a apostrophe
            if(word[i] == 39)
            {
                index = MAX_CHARS - 1;
            }
            // gets nummeric value of letter
            else
            {
                index = tolower(word[i]) - 'a';
            }


            next_node = current->children[index];

            // creates new node if letter didnt exists before
            if(next_node == NULL)
            {
                next_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
                current->children[index] = next_node;
                current->is_word = false;
                printf("new letter: %c\n", word[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("letter: %c\n", word[i]);
            }
            // checks for end of the word
            if(i == word_length - 1)
            {
                next_node->is_word = true;
            }
            current = next_node;
        }   
}
return true;
}
```

The node is defined by:

```
// node

typedef struct node
{
    bool is_word;
    struct node* children[27];
}
node;
```

Comment: Could be a buffer overflow. What's the definition of `word`?

Comment: acclimatization is possibly the largest word encountered so far in a dictionary. Are you sure your buffer is large enough? The largest word in Hansard (UK Parliament records) is floccinaucinihilipilification. Make sure your buffer is large enough for that too.

Comment: A lot of context is needed, what kind of list are you using, how did you initialize it, how did you define `word`, all those things are important. Your code might be exhibiting undefined behavior, which can be caused by multiple reasons.

Comment: thank you for the fast replies. I added some more context hope that will help. And iharob thanks for the tips i will fix them right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocate very little space for `word`, it's probably `8` or `4` bytes depending on your platform.

You are allocating space for *1 `char` pointer*, so when you read from the file `LENGTH` characters you can be storing bytes beyond the limits of the allocated buffer. The problem is, that the behavior is **undefined** thus the program might work or it might stop or anything can happen.

You don't need to allocate it dynamically, just like this it's ok

```
char word[100];
while (fgets(word, sizeof(word), file) != NULL) ...
/*                    ^ this only works with arrays,   */
/*                      the benefit is that you can    */
/*                      change the definition of word  */
/*                      and resize it without changing */
/*                      this part.                     */
/*                                                     */
/*       It will NOT work if you use `malloc()'        */
```

Also, you would have a memory leak if `fopen()` failes, every `malloc()` requires a corresponding `free()`.

**Suggestion**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < word_length; i++)
```

can be written like this too

```
for (int i = 0; ((word[i] != '\n') && (word[i] != '\0')); i++)
```

and you avoid calling `strlen()` which will also iterate through the characters.

Comment: awesome was breaking my head on this for way to long, to see i fixed by you guys in a view min :D Thanks you so much!! i changed the size of word to : word = malloc(LENGTH) and it works now ! ^^

Comment: But be careful, `malloc()` does not make any sense in this case if you intend to keep it's size fixed.

Comment: yea you are right :P I removed malloc and. Thanks again it works great! ^^ will focus on making the code more logic now.

Answer (score 4):

```
char* word = malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

Depending on platform it can be `4` or `8` . You need to allocate more memory.

```
char* word;
word = malloc(LENGTH);    // LENGTH as you use it here while (fgets(word,LENGTH,dict) != NULL)
if(word!=NULL){            // and checking if malloc is successful

   // your code 
    free(word);               // freeing allocated memory
    return true;
 }
else {                   // executed only if malloc fails
        //handle error
  }
```

You can give any desired size.

*Note* - Using function `free()` , you need to free every time you allocate memory.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! your anwers helped me alot, but since iharob came up with more or less the same anwser earlier i give him the check mark credits. :)

Comment: @Dutchguy  That doesn't matter . Glad your problem got solved :)